# SQL - Add a counter for each occurrence of a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have a simple select that returns something like 
(*eg. SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC FROM sourcetabel*)

```
Column A - Column B   - Column C
John     - Something  - 123
John     - Something  - 456
Mark     - Something  - 123
Mark     - Something  - 456
```

Now I would like to have a counter in here that does the following:
Each time an occurrence is found in Column A it adds a number to Column B
This would then mean:

```
Column A - Column B   - Column C
John     - Something **1**  - 123
John     - Something **2**  - 456
Mark     - Something **1**  - 123
Mark     - Something **2**  - 456
```

Anybody got a clue on how I can do this easily?

FYI: I'm using MSSQL

Thanks!

Comment: Use Group by clause

Comment: what rdbms are you working with? what version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat()` and the ANSI-standard `row_number()` function:

```
select a,
       concat(a, ' **', row_number() over (partition by a, b order by b), '**') as new_b,
       c
from t;
```

The exact function for `concat()` varies depending on the database.

Comment: Partitioning seems to be required as otherwise I just had a single counter going up for each row. @GordonLinoff your example translated beautifully to my query! (the ** btw were just for markdown:) I just needed the number)

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports it, use the row_number function:

```
SELECT A, B, C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A,B,C ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM TableName
```

(the order of the rows is arbitrary since they are identical anyway)

Answer (score 0):

For MSSQL,

> select A,B+cast((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName ORDER BY
>   (SELECT NULL))) as varchar(10)) as B,C from sourcetabel